# Is it possible to solve this bitwise equation?

Tags: logic

I have been googling but I can't get a conclusion. I have this equation:

```
a = ((b ^ x) >> c) & d | e * ((b ^ x) & f)
```

Would it be possible to solve this bitwise equation? Assuming all values are known except x.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the meaning of the symbols used? (*,|,etc.)

Comment: That symbols are [bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Bitwise_Operators), and * is a common multiplication. @zoli

Comment: I still don't understand: What does this mean: ((b ^ x) >> c)? Does that mean that c is the sign propagated right shift of b XOR x?

Comment: Yes, for example if you have `((20 ^ 30) >> 15)` it would be equal to 0 because `20 ^ 30` is equal to 10 and `10 >> 15` is equal to zero @zoli

Comment: You can use `(b ^ x) >> c = (b >> c) ^ (x >> c)` ([proof](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/59274/15509), at least for binary shifts) and then `((b >> c) ^ (x >> c)) & d = ((b >> c) & d) ^ ((x >> c) & d))` ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction#Properties)). Not sure if that helps, though.

Comment: Mmm... Interesting. But how can I use that to introduce `a` in the expression and clear `x`? @ComFreek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested in the answer, finally I solved it with the help of bruteforce.

First, I concluded that the result of `((b ^ x) >> c) & d` was always relatively low (in a range of 0-50) and most of times 0 or 1 so I transformed the equation into this:

```
a = y | e * ((b ^ x) & f)
```

And defined the value of `y` with a loop that increases `y` progresively from 0.

Then I setted up another loop that defines the value of `x` and then checked for each value if the equality is met.

Since I was getting a lot of false positives, I decided to check if current value of `y` is correct. Now I know `x`, so:

```
((b ^ x) >> c) & d = y
```

If the equality is met I have found a solution, if not the loop continues until find a valid solution.

Sometimes I get duplicated solutions. For example, in one case I got two solutions: 7957 and 73493. Curiously, that numbers translated to hexadecimal are: 1F15 and 11F15. And in most of cases duplicated solutions follow that rule.

Answer (score 1):

Let `g=b^x`, then we can solve for it and use `x=b^g`.

`h=g>>c`$=\left\lfloor\frac{g}{2^c}\right\rfloor$

By unravelling it (using the arithmetic versions of the AND and OR functions typically used for independent probabilities), `a=h&d|e*(g&f)` is equivalent to$$a=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\left(\left(\left(\left\lfloor\frac{g}{2^{c+i}}\right\rfloor\%2\right)*\left(\left\lfloor\frac{d}{2^i}\right\rfloor\%2\right)+\left(\left\lfloor\frac{e*(g\&f)}{2^i}\right\rfloor\%2\right)-\\\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \left(\left\lfloor\frac{g}{2^{c+i}}\right\rfloor\%2\right)*\left(\left\lfloor\frac{d}{2^i}\right\rfloor\%2\right)*\left(\left\lfloor\frac{e*(g\&f)}{2^i}\right\rfloor\%2\right)\right)*2^i\right)$$
The hard part is the multiplication by `e` (being that mixed arithmetic and bitwise operators can produce [complex behaviour](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/%7Eknuth/fasc1a.ps.gz), as multiplication is equivalent to convolution with carries), each bit of `h` provides an additional constraint in the simultaneous equation.

If you define the recursive function$$\mathrm{λ}(0)=0; \mathrm{λ}(n)=\mathrm{λ}\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\right)+1$$ (equivalent to Python's `int.bit_length()`, the maximum `0`-indexed bit position plus `1`), you have the bounds $\mathrm{λ}(a*b)\ge \mathrm{λ}(a)+\mathrm{λ}(b)$, $\mathrm{λ}(a\&b)=\min(\mathrm{λ}(a),\mathrm{λ}(b))$ and $\mathrm{λ}(a|b)=\max(\mathrm{λ}(a),\mathrm{λ}(b))$, which may be used to find an upper bound for each of the set of working values of `g`. (It will not be unique, and may not be satisfiable at all.)

In general, this problem is equivalent to finding a set of boolean inputs to  a function that cause it to return true, and (if you implement it explicitly as a configuration of logic gates) can generally be solved in specific cases (ie. values of `x` may be found efficiently, without guarantee that they comprise the complete set) by use of an SAT solver.